# How to delete post in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

I'm making a food sharing site using firebase I'm trying to add a delete post option so when a food item is taken the user can delete the post so they aren't contacted about something they've already given away. I have managed to get the firebase remove function working but it just deletes all posts not just one. I'm using the push option when sending the data to my database as I need users to be able to make multiple posts but I don't know what the name of the post ids are to select them.

This is the code that sends the donations to the database

```
function submitDonation() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user) {
        var userid = user.uid;
        var email = user.email;
        var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
        firebaseRef.child("Donations").push({
            user: userid,
            email: email,
            food: document.getElementById("foodType").value,
            animal: document.getElementById("animalType").value,
            expire: document.getElementById("expirationDate").value,
            travel: document.getElementById("travelDistance").value,
            location: document.getElementById("what3wordsLocation").value,
            contact: document.getElementById("contactPreference").value,
            time: document.getElementById("timePreference").value
        }); 
    }
}
```

and this is the code retrieving and drawing the data on the page. I'm using jquery to display my posts so sorry it looks a bit messy but I've basically got a button that calls a function and I need the button's id to match the id of the post but I don't know how to call that. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm still relatively new to firebase so still working on the basics aha.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Donations");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var food = snap.child("food").val();
    var animal = snap.child("animal").val();
    var expire = snap.child("expire").val();
    var travel = snap.child("travel").val();
    var location = snap.child("location").val();
    var contact = snap.child("contact").val();
    var time = snap.child("time").val();


    $("#listingDonations").append(
        "<div id='donationBox' class='three columns'><div id='donationItem'><button onclick='deletePost()'>Delete</button><p><b>Type of Food:</b> " + food + "</p><p><b>Type of Animal:</b> " + animal + "</p><p><b>Expiration Date:</b> " + expire + "</p><p><b>Travel Distance:</b> " + travel + "</p><p><b>Contact Details:</b> " + contact + "</p><p><b>Preferred Contact Time:</b> " + time + "</p><a href='https://www.what3words.com/"+ location +"'>Location</a></div></div>"
    );
})

function deletePost() {

}
```

Ive deleted the code I'd written in the deletePost function as it didn't work and is probably wrong anyway.

Comment: Hi, one approach is: put all the data in an `array`, if something is added you retrieve the `array` from the db, change it in your function and then `update` the db.